# An error occurred while executing doInBackground(), Can't create the session

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I tried to register user by using AsyncTask. When running the application it creates a user and throws an exception like this.

```
01-20 11:57:42.461: D/User Created!(2977): {"message":"Username Successfully Added!","success":1}
01-20 11:57:42.571: W/dalvikvm(2977): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e19438)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at com.example.rp.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:329)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at com.example.rp.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-20 11:57:42.591: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):     ... 5 more
```

This is the my activity asynctask

```
class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {       
        int success;
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", dob));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gender));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_reg, "POST", params);

            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, TestTab.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                session.createLoginSession("RandB", email);

                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            } else {
                showAlertDialog(Register.this, "Registration Error...", "Please register again...", false);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

with the user creation. I want to create session and start new activity. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is line 329? also you can;t show a dialog from doInbackground if you are showing coz i see a method  `showAlertDialog`. Also move the startActivity code to `onPostExecute`

Comment: copy `success` check part into `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Move your code for start session an showDialog into `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

Do this work  in onPostExecute() method

```
if (success == 1) {

              Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
              Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, TestTab.class);
              finish();
              startActivity(i);
              session.createLoginSession("RandB", email);
              return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            } else {
                showAlertDialog(Register.this, "Registration Error...", "Please register      again...", false);

            }
```

Comment: @anuruddhika post what is line 329.

Comment: @Raghunandan session.createLoginSession("RandB", email);

Comment: @anuruddhika session is null. where is it initialized

Comment: @Raghunandani did not initialized it.so i did it now.it's working now. thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

change task to:

```
   class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {       
        int success;
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", dob));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gender));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_reg, "POST", params);

            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                session.createLoginSession("RandB", email);

                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            } else {
                return null;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
           if(result!=null){
               Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, TestTab.class);

                startActivity(i);
        session.createLoginSession("RandB", email);
          finish();
         }else{
showAlertDialog(Register.this, "Registration Error...", "Please register again...", false);
}
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```